# lua: lscript.lua:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'core')

Tags: lua

I have written the below code in order to get the difference between two timestamps from a wireshark sniffer capture.
Im getting this error

Lua: lscript.lua:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'core')
stack traceback:
lscript.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in ?

Code:

```
local my_protocol = Proto("TSFDiff", "MAC Beacon Timestamp Diff")

local mac_timestamp = ProtoField.uint64("my_protocol.mac_timestamp", "MAC Timestamp", base.DEC)
local beacon_timestamp = ProtoField.uint64("my_protocol.beacon_timestamp", "Beacon Timestamp", base.DEC)
local time_difference = ProtoField.int64("my_protocol.time_difference", "Time Difference", base.DEC)

my_protocol.fields = { mac_timestamp, beacon_timestamp, time_difference }

function my_protocol.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = my_protocol.name
    local subtree = tree:add(my_protocol, buffer(),"MY Protocol Data")
     

    local mac_ts = buffer(8, 8):le_uint64()
    local beacon_ts = buffer(72, 8):le_uint64()



    local diff = beacon_ts - mac_ts

    subtree:add(mac_timestamp, mac_ts)
    subtree:add(beacon_timestamp, beacon_ts)
    subtree:add(time_difference, diff)
end

DissectorTable.get("udp.port"):add(7006, my_protocol)
```